# Autohotkey-Gui-Edit : Can section and key be read in different color in ini file?

Tags: autohotkey

**How to read sections and keys in different colors in gui edit**

I'm reading an .ini file, but I can't display the section and keys in different colors.
reads in only 1 color

a.ini : ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

```
[title]
number=test
```

code : ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

```
FileRead, file, a.ini
Gui, Font, s14 cBlue
Gui Add, Edit, w435 h400 vfile, %file%
Gui, show
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control type
[GUI Edit](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#Edit)
is an area where free-form text can be entered.
It does not do highlighting to display elements in colors.

You need to parse the text yourself and create the highlights yourself.

To help with the task, you may convert the text into HTML, perhaps
using Regular Expressions, and display it using the library
[HTMLText](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/24509-htmltext-101-write-html-style-text-to-a-gui/).

An example given in the documentation for how the colored text is to
be created is:

```
<fGeorgia><w100>Light text in Georgia</w></f><w1000>Heaviest text</w>Normal Text<u><i><b>This is underlined, italic and bold </b></i></u><cff0000><d>This is red and Deleted</d></c>
```

Comment: Is it impossible to display line 1 and line 2 in different font color using a loop with "FileReadLine" ?

Comment: The most you can do is select one line to distinguish it from the other.